# Upload image using flutter and NODEJS API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dart

I try to do an image upload with flutter and nodejs but it seems that the file field is not taken into account on the mobile application. The test with postman works normally and the file is loaded but with the flutter application, req.file always returns undefined in nodejs console. Thank you for your help.

**NODEJS**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const multer = require('multer')

const BASE_URL = '/api/v1.0.0'


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "./db/events/covers")
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + "--" + file.originalname)
    },
})

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype == "images/png") {
        cb(null, true)
    } else {
        cb(null, false)
    }
}

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 6,
    },
    fileFilter: fileFilter
})

router.route(BASE_URL + '/events/create').post(upload.single("img"), async(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    const response = {
        message: "Image mis à jour"
    }
    return res.status('200').send(response)
})

module.exports = router
```

**DART**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class CreateEvent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateEventState createState() => _CreateEventState();
}

class _CreateEventState extends State<CreateEvent> {
  File? selectedImage;
  String? message = "";

  uploadImage() async {
    final request = http.MultipartRequest(
        "POST", Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.65:9000/api/v1.0.0/events/create"));
    final headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"};
    request.files.add(http.MultipartFile('img',
        selectedImage!.readAsBytes().asStream(), selectedImage!.lengthSync(),
        filename: selectedImage!.path.split("/").last));
    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    final response = await request.send();
    http.Response res = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
    final resJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
    message = resJson['message'];
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedImage =
        await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    selectedImage = File(pickedImage!.path);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text(
          "Publier un évènement",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            selectedImage == null
                ? Text('Sélectionnez une image')
                : Image.file(selectedImage!),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: uploadImage,
              child: Text("Upload"),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: getImage,
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this  line

```
request.files.add(http.MultipartFile('img',
    selectedImage!.readAsBytes().asStream(), selectedImage!.lengthSync(),
    filename: selectedImage!.path.split("/").last));
```

with this one

```
request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('img',
    selectedImage!.readAsBytes()), selectedImage!.lengthSync(),
    filename: selectedImage!.path.split("/").last));
```

so it can accept the image as a byte format